# Multiplicative group of a field contains maximal n-1 elements with order n

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $n\in \mathbb N,n>1$.

I want to show that the multiplicative group $K$\ $\{0\}$ contains maximal $n-1$ elements with order $n$.

I actually don't have any ideas how to solve this one. So I will be thankful for any kind of help (ideas at first and if it does not help me, then full solution...)

Thanks !:)

Comment: More precisely, there are at most $\phi(n)$ such elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If char$\,K\mid n\;$, say $\;n=pr\;,\;\;p\;$ a prime,   then $\;x^n-1=x^{pr}-1=(x^r-1)^p\;$ and this polynomial has at most $\;r<n\;$ different roots in $\;K^*\;$ and we're done.

Otherwise, define

$$W_n:=\left\{\;a\in K\;;\;w^n=1\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\;\right\}$$

It's easy to check $\;W_n\;$ is a subgroup of $\;K^*\;$ , and since it is finite it is then cyclic.

Since we know that there are exactly $\;\varphi(n)\;$ generators of this subgroup ,$\;\varphi=$ Euler's Function, we now get what we want by observing that $\;\varphi(n)\le n-1\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;$

Comment: Not all roots of $x^n-1$ have order $n$.

Comment: Rats, I missed th "order" thing!. Thanks, editing...or deleting.

Comment: So, its correct now?

Comment: @Naim, unless you don't understand something specific that question is odd: either you can follows the logic and terms and arguments or you can't. It isn't right because I or anyone else says, but because it is...or not.

Comment: Why I can't just say that the polynomial $X^n-1$ has exactly n zeros. One of the zeros is $1 \in K$, hence there are maximal n-1 non trivial elements which satisfy $X^n-1$. Since all elements with order $n$, fulfill the equation, the number of elements with order $n$ is bounded by the number of the non trivial roots of the polynomial. Why this does not work?

Comment: It does, @Naim... **if** char $\,K\nmid n\;$, otherwise it can have way less than $\;n\;$ roots, as pointed out above.